# How can I get rid of 504 timeout error on web3 when calling a smart contract method?

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I am not sure what to do, I have increased the timeout by doing this

```
var options = {
    timeout: 60000 * 2, // ms
    // Enable auto reconnection
    reconnect: {
        auto: true,
        delay: 5000, // ms
        maxAttempts: 5,
        onTimeout: false
    }
};
const web3 = new Web3( new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(web3Settings.provider, options));
```

but I am still getting 504 timeout error sometimes  on  calling function of a contract

```
2022-02-16T08:19:00.456908+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:22) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: "<html>\r\n<head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
2022-02-16T08:19:00.456917+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.InvalidResponse (/app/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:43:16)
2022-02-16T08:19:00.456918+00:00 app[web.1]: at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/app/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js:95:32)
2022-02-16T08:19:00.456918+00:00 app[web.1]: at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/app/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:22)
2022-02-16T08:19:00.456919+00:00 app[web.1]: at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/app/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:208:14)
2022-02-16T08:19:00.456919+00:00 app[web.1]: at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/app/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:318:14)
2022-02-16T08:19:00.456919+00:00 app[web.1]: at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:289:61)
```

I am using bsc testnet network.

Comment: where is your smart contract located?

Comment: smart contract deployed on bsc testnet

Answer (score 1):

If you're in front-end, than we should init web3 using

```
new Web3(window.ethereum);
await window.ethereum.enable();
```

If you're in backend, than use they HttpProvider is a good choice.

There's something you can do:

- Make sure that the rpc you're using is valid. May be it point to a wrong address.
- Try to interact with another SC to see whether the code work or not.

Comment: I am using it at the backend. it will work sometimes and fails sometimes. it is not stable, right now. it is working

Comment: If you're testing in bsctestnet, then nevermind. It's well known for the non stable. Alternatively can can use Alchemy or Ganache for the testing purpose. They run locally so you wont   be annoyed with this kind of 503.

Comment: Thank you @PySoL